# AWS: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create a new elastic beanstalk with AWS but it gives me this error.

> Stack named 'aws ... -stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].

There is really not many options for me to change something.

not sure if it is related but right afte this error I'm getting another one

> Creating Auto Scaling group named: ...-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-.... failed. Reason: This account is currently blocked and not recognized as a valid account. Please contact aws-verification @ amazon.com if you have questions. Launching EC2 instance failed.

I send email to aws-verification @ amazon.com, but nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contact AWS Customer Service (which is different to Customer Support).

They can advise you on the status of the account.

Go to: https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/v1#/case/create?issueType=customer-service

Comment: Thanks. It turns out it was a problem on their side. This problem happened only in Sydney, when Ohio was working perfectly fine. Today Sydney is also working fine. It is not the first time when Melbournians struggle because of Sydney guys :)

Answer (score 0):

This is done to prevent any fraudulent activities with accounts. When a new account is created, based on some context, AWS will decided the level of resources you can start. For example, initially they may not allow large instances.
You need to contact AWS support and git it fixed. How to do that is given in the following video.
[How to activate a blocked AWS account & increase vCPU limits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkmaxX3VBP8)